# Unable to access to the postgresql database server remotely

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, postgresql-8.4

I noticed that my postgresql is accessible only in my localhost after I issued the following command in linux terminal (Suse Linux  - SLES 11 SP2 64bit):

```
# netstat -an 10.64.72.202 | grep 5432
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          127.0.0.1:33304         ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 ::1:5432                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33304         127.0.0.1:5432          ESTABLISHED 
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     2739454 /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     4225466 /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     4104233 /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     2839271 /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     2816569 /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

My question is how I can make the postgresql server accessible from out world. I can ping to the machine where postgressql is installed but I cannot connect to the database itself. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to enable remote access for postgres on your machine.

[Here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/postgres-allow-remote-access-tcp-connection.html) is an tutorial which helped me to accomplish this for my setup.

Its an quite easy step-by-step guide for postgres versions < 7.x AND 8.x and newer.

Hope this helped, have Fun!

Comment: You should post the related commands and comments useful to the question in order to avoid dead links, but thanks anyway :)